# W/System ( 9284): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication, android-emulator

I am getting this error when run the project in emulator and for this the firebase authentication does not work. But it's ok when I run it in google chrome or edge. My emulator's internet connection is ok. Also firebase authentication with email/password is enabled. I am trying to solve the problem from the last work. But all the solution from stackoverflow is not working. Please give me a solution.